# Javascript - Replace lots of if statements

Tags: javascript

I have a a couple of different radio buttons which return an ethnicity and a gender. The script runs inside an internal application so rather than returning "boy", "girl" or "both" I get back 7707330, 7707333, and 7707336. Similar from the ethnicity radio button.

I then need to validate data based on the combonation of ethnicity and gender. This was a pretty simple task but I have ended up with 15 if statements! It all works as it should, but there must be a cleaner solution?

```
    function test(radioResults) {

    var1 = radioResults[0].toString();
    var2 = radioResults[1].toString();
    roll = parseFloat(parent.roll);

    if (var2 == '7707330') {
        gender = 'boy';
    }
    if (var2 == '7707333') {
        gender = 'girl';
    }
    if (var2 == '7707336') {
        gender = 'both';
    }

    if (var1 == '7707341') {
        maori(gender);
    }
    if (var1 == '7707344') {
        pasifika(gender);
    }
    if (var1 == '7707347') {
        all(gender);
    }
}

function maori(gender) {
    //Maori 
    if (gender == 'boy') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getMBoys);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'girl') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getMGirls);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'both') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalM);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
}

function pasifika(gender) {
    //Pasifika
    if (gender == 'boy') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getPBoys);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'girl') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getPGirls);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'both') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalP);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
}

function all(gender) {
    //All
    if (gender == 'boy') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getBoys);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'girl') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getGirls);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'both') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalRoll);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
}

function validation(ethnicity) {

    percent = ethnicity * 5 / 100;

    if (ethnicity - percent > roll || (ethnicity + percent < roll)) {
        parent.document.getElementById('CF_7784443').value = "FAIL";
    } else {
        parent.document.getElementById('CF_7784443').value = "PASS";
    }
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 7):

One option is to have a map from key -> value

for example:

```
var var2 = radioResults[1].toString();
var gender = {'7707330': 'boy',
               '7707333': 'girl',
               '7707336': 'both'}[var2];
```

You could even put functions as the values. For example:

```
var var1 = radioResults[0].toString()
{'7707341': maori,
 '7707344': pasifika,
 '7707347': all}[var1](gender);
```

Answer (score 4):

As Michael Deardeuff has already pointed out, in this particular case, maps are a good answer.

But the generic answer to "I have a lot of `if (var == value)` statements" is "use `switch (var)`."  A `switch` reads better - it lets you read a single path and ignore the rest, knowing they won't be used for this value.  For example:

```
function test(radioResults) {

    roll = parseFloat(parent.roll);   // This is unused
    switch (radioResults[1].toString())
    {
        case '7707330':
            gender = 'boy';
            break;
        case '7707333':
            gender = 'girl';
            break;
        case '7707336':
            gender = 'both';
            break;
        default:
            /* Your code ignores the possibility of an unexpected value */
    }

    switch (radioResults[0].toString())
    {
        case '7707341':
            maori(gender);
            break;
        case '7707344':
            pasifika(gender);
            break;
        case  '7707347':
            all(gender);
            break;
        default:
            /* Your code ignores the possibility of an unexpected value */
    }
}
```

Or, in this simple case, even:

```
function test(radioResults) {

    switch (radioResults[1].toString())
    {
        case '7707330': gender = 'boy'; break;
        case '7707333': gender = 'girl'; break;
        case '7707336': gender = 'both'; break;
    }

    switch (radioResults[0].toString())
    {
        case '7707341': maori(gender); break;
        case '7707344': pasifika(gender); break;
        case '7707347': all(gender); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the other two commenters have noted, there are simpler ways of expressing those if-statements. However, I think there is something more important that needs to be addressed in your code: organisation. You've already made some good progress at separating out logic into small, contained functions. However there are two issues I immediately notice:

1. A function should try to follow the Single Responsibility Principle – it should only focus on one thing.
2. Your functions rely on a the global state of several variables, this can cause many unexpected bugs and make them hard to track down – pass your functions everything they need to know.

So, with those two things in mind, this is a better way to write your code using a similar style:

```
function validate(parent, radioResults) {
  var gen = gender(radioResults[0].toString()),
      eth = ethnicity(radioResults[1].toString()),
      mult = multiplier(parent, gen, eth),
      roll = parseFloat(parent.roll, 10),
      element = parent.document.getElementById('CF_7784443');

  if (isValidPercentage(mult, roll))
    element.value = 'PASS';
  else
    element.value = 'FAIL';
}

function gender(val) {
  switch(val) {
    case '7707330':
      return 'boy';

    case '7707333':
      return 'girl';

    case '7707336':
      return 'both';

    default:
      // Nadda
  }
}

function ethnicity(val) {
  switch(val) {
    case '7707341':
      return 'maori';

    case '7707344':
      return 'pasifika';

    case '7707347':
      return 'all';

    default:
      // Nadda
  }
}

function multiplier(parent, gender, ethnicity) {
  switch(ethnicity) {
    // All
    case 'all':
      if (gender == 'boy')
        return parseFloat(parent.getBoys, 10);
      else if (gender == 'girl')
        return parseFloat(parent.getGirls, 10);
      else
        return parseFloat(parent.getTotalRoll, 10);

    // Maori
    case 'maori':
      if (gender == 'boy')
        return parseFloat(parent.getMBoys, 10);
      else if (gender == 'girl')
        return parseFloat(parent.getMGirls, 10);
      else
        return parseFloat(parent.getTotalM, 10);

    // Pasifika
    case 'pasifika':
      if (gender == 'boy')
        return parseFloat(parent.getPBoys, 10);
      else if (gender == 'girl')
        return parseFloat(parent.getPGirls, 10);
      else
        return parseFloat(parent.getTotalP, 10);

    default:
      // Nadda
  }
}

function isValidPercentage(multiplier, roll) {
  var percent = multiplier * 5 / 100;

  return ! (multiplier - percent > roll || (multiplier + percent < roll));
}
```

As you can see I have renamed some of the functions to more accurately represent their purpose, I have ensured that I pass everything I need into my functions as arguments instead of using global variables, and finally I have made each function responsible for a single task.

Answer (score 0):

If something will execute on every path of your `if`s, and the `if`s are arranged in a way it will execute only one of them, you can move that logic outside on the bottom:

```
if (gender == 'boy') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getMBoys);
    //why run...      validation(ethnicity);
}
if (gender == 'girl') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getMGirls);
    //this line...    validation(ethnicity);
}
if (gender == 'both') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalM);
    //on every if?     validation(ethnicity);
}
validation(ethnicity); //move it outside here :)
```

If you are going to apply something to all of the `if`s, you don't need to apply them each time, you can apply the change later on:

```
if (...) {
    //why use...   ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getBoys);
   ethnicity = parent.getBoys;
}
if (...) {
    //parseFloat...   ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getGirls);
    ethnicity = parent.getGirls;
}
if (...) {
    //on each one?   ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalRoll);
    ethnicity = parent.getTotalRoll;
}
ethnicity = parseFloat(ethnicity); //do the change
```